# NSNumber is not the same as its floatValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I came up strange behaviour of `NSNumber`.

basically my code gets json from API call:

```
id json_response = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:data
                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                             error:&error];
```

and stored as `NSDictionary`

then I got `NSNumber` from it and using `NSNumberFormatter` to convert it to a string, but...

```
NSNumber * avgNumber = [[_tableDataArray objectAtIndex:index ]
                            objectForKey:kTrendsKeyAvgScoreFloat];
```

here is formatting output:

```
 NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString * retString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

I got strange behaviour when `NSNumber` has value of 1.05

```
(__NSCFNumber *) avgNumber = 0x0000000155923800 (float)1.050000
```

But with code above it was printing (instead of expected 1.1):

```
1
```

However when I checked float value

```
float avg = [avgNumber floatValue];
```

it turns out that

```
    Printing description of avg:
(double) avg = 1.0499999523162842
```

Even if I try to round it to 2 decimal points

```
    avg = roundf(avg * 100); // here 105
    avg = avg / 100; // and here is  1.0499999523162842 again
```

However if I test the code and put 1.05 manually inside `NSDictionary` everything works as expected.

If someone could explain why is that? And how to preserve every time proper display?

Comment: It's not clear what's your issue. Is it that `NSNumberFormatter` produces `1` instead of `1.1`?  In which case it's because it rounds down.  Or are you confused by the number being `1.04999` instead of `1.05`?  In which case that's just a floating point rounding error.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Yes, I'm confused because I have 1.05 and it should be rounded to 1.1 not 1.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a value of 1.05 cannot be represented exactly by a floating point number. This is only possible for values that are sums of (positive or negative) powers of 2. One can, thus, exactly represent values like 1 (=2^0) or 1.03125 (= 2^0 + 2^-5), but the best approximation to 1.5 is in your case 1.0499999523162842.
Now when you initialize an `NSNumberFormatter`, and do no set its `roundingMode` property, its default value is `kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven`, which means the number will be rounded „towards the nearest integer, or towards an even number if equidistant.“
So if your number is 1.0499999523162842, it will be rounded to 1.0, and this is output as 1.

Comment: that's perfectly clear to me, thank you. So how to show proper number to end user? Because even using correct rounding mode will not help because it will round 1.0499999523162842 not 1.05

Comment: If you want to round not towards an integer, but towards half of an integer (in your case towards 1,05), you could do:  
If x is the value to be rounded, round 2x towards an integer, and divide the result by 2. E.g. 1,0499 * 2 = 2,0998, rounded = 2,1 / 2 = 1,05. But, as said, 1,05 cannot be expressed exactly by a floating point number.